# My Query String is empty

Tags: jsp, query-string

I have a `jsp` file where I send two parameters using the following url.

```
var url = 'abc_user_history.jsp?where='+where+'&stock_number=' + StockNumber;
window.open(url, 'Special_Value_History','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1500,height=900');
```

Here I am only getting `stock_number`, where is always `null`... in where I have some SQL query, ex:

```
where=where stock_id like '4575%' and stock_name like 'abc%'
```

In the `abc_user_history.jsp` I always has where as `null`. However I am able to get `stock_number` value. Please suggest how to pass that where value...

Comment: What is the value of `where` before you build your url variable. If it's null then it isn't getting anything from your backend

Comment: Please DO NOT put query where conditions as request parameters... it is the best case scenario for a malicious user to perform SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Maybe your where variable begins with an & ?

Comment: @richardtz No I am not using & before ...

Comment: @Swift Thanks I am new to this, then how can I pass that where value to the JSP?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS where is not null, I have value in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many anti-patterns here i don't know where to start :|

If you really need your where parameter to be one single, dynamic parameter, 
you can pass a String with all the pairs field=value separated by a custom separator, 
and then parse them in Java (using a StringTokenizer) and mount them in a Where condition in the Action.

Example of where variable:

where="stock_id:::'4575%';;;stock_name:::'abc%';;;"
(::: means that the field name is over and its starting the value, ;;; means that that pair is over and you are eventually starting to read a new pair).

of course this will break if some of your values contains ";;;" or ":::" (you should sanitize them first with javascript).

By the way, this is not good because you shouldn't concat your java mounted string to the query string, but inject your tokenized values in a PreparedStatement (so the PreparedStatement will check and sanitize them for you).

But i suggest to pass every parameter as a single parameter (not a ?where= but a ?stock_id=xxx&stock_name=yyy&... in your URL).

And you should use POST to post a form, not GET that should only be used to read pages, not to post stuff (not possible using window.open(), but you can post a form from an anchor with target="_blank" and onclick="javascript:document.getElementById['myForm'].submit();")

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks let me try parsing each variables. However the problem is abc_user_history.jsp is already used by many other pages. Hence editing that page with all get parameters is not allowed. That's why I thought to send the where parameter itself..

Comment: Noting now that you have no Java, only JSP scriptlet... then yes, post Where var with pairs, then in the JSP parse it with a StringTokenizer...

Answer (score 1):

passing query in get params is very dangerous, search for parameterized query in java, there is many documents on it.
Are you calling jsp page from javascript? Be aware of quotes in your string.

Comment: Yes I am calling the jsp from Javascript.. What should I do with the quotes?

Comment: In your example there is an error on where condition:
        where=where stock_id like '4575%' and stock_name like 'abc%'

When you need quotes in a string you must pay attention, you can use for example double quotes or escape char:  where="where stock_id like '4575%' and stock_name like 'abc%'" you can find many examples googgling on this subject.

Comment: Thanks Fabbri, That is a good tip. Will take care about it. This issue got solved by using encrypt string. so the real culprit was the blank spaces...